# Строки в c#. String \ StringBuilder

Tags: c#

Ребят, у меня возникли вопросы по строкам в c#.

> 1. Чем отличается класс String от StringBuilder?
> 2. Зачем нужно такое разделение?
> 3. В чем преимущества того и другого?
> 4. Что из этого лучше использовать?
> 5. Почему StringBuilder лучше использовать для работы с большими объемами текста?

По возможности ответьте с примерами. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`String` - это строки. Они неизменяемые т.е. конкретную строку нельзя подправить/дописать/укоротить. Любые операции над строками приводят к созданию новой строки (с копированием всего текста). При этом старая строка уходит в мусор (если у вас не остается на нее ссылки).

Так сделано из соображений

- Экономии памяти - не надо подстраховываться и копировать строку "на всякий случай" при передаче куда-то в другой метод. Он ее точно никак не испортит.
- Производительности - можно высчитывать хэш строки один раз, и не заморачиваться с поддержанием его актуальности. Это дает быстрые сравнения строк на равенство (особенно если строки разные).
- Безопасности - код может спокойно работать с пришедшими извне строками, не опасаясь что кто-то влезет в строку по дороге.
- Простоты работы с несколькими потоками - нет проблемы одновременных изменений.

Соответственно, при сборке большой строки из многих маленких эта особенность - неизменяемость строк - приводит к множественному копированию данных и к генерации большого количества мусора.

Для решения этой проблемы есть класс `StringBuilder`. Это не "строка", а класс для сборки строк из кусков, позволяющий в конце получить результирующую строку вызовом `StringBuilder.ToString()`.

- Если вам надо просто работать со строками - используете `String`
- Если вам надо собрать одну большую строку из пачки маленьких - используете `StringBuilder`

Answer (score 8):

1. `String` **не изменяемый** тип. То есть если Вы создадите строку потом добавите ей несколько символов то это будет не старая модифицированная строка, а в памяти аллоцируется новый объект `System.String`, который будет содержать в себе новую строку. При этом старый объект продолжает существовать в куче пока не произойдет сборка мусора. Такой вот безобидный код:

   ```
   string str = string.Empty;

   for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
   {
       str += "a";
   }
   ```

Создаст в памяти 1000 потенциальных кандидатов для GC.

При вызове метода например `Append` объекта StringBuilder будет изменятся уже существующая область памяти.

2. Что бы не загружать `GC` лишними операциями.
3. Преимущества очевидны -- Если у вас одна строка (например константа) то типа `System.String` вполне достаточно. Если же вы заранее знаете что будете много изменять строку то класс `StringBuilder` упростить жизнь `GC` и `CLR`. Врятли это как то скажется на производительности, если у Вас не большая система и реально вы не почувствуете разницу. Но когда в проекте идет работа с миллионами строк то тогда `StringBuilder` не заменим (если конечно же Вы не напишете свой механизм работы со строками на неуправляемом коде или в unsafe-коде).

Ответы на остальные вопросы очевидны.

Эта тема очень **детально** описана в книге "*CRL via C#*" Джеффри Рихтера.