# Как вставить в уже имеющуюся строку string,символ '*' указанное количество раз в указанное место в строке?

Tags: c#, строки

Есть строка string  `s = "....."`,нужно вставить в строку s символ '*' указанное мной количество раз,чтобы получилось к примеру, `s = ".***."`.

Comment: Строки в C# неизменяемы. Хотите эффективный доступ по индексу — используйте `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = s.Substring(0, index) + new string('*', repCount) + s.Substring(index + repCount); // index - индекс, с которого менять; repCount - количество звездочек
```

Answer (score 8):

```
s = s.Insert(1, new string('*', 5));
```

И не надо никаких циклов.

Comment: Вас не смущает, что при такой вставке из строки "....." не получится строки ".***."? В вопросе указана именно такая трансформация.

Comment: @kodv, нет, не смущает, видимо автор ошибся с примером, что подтверждает принятый ответ. Вставка есть вставка, в примере у автора описана замена.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = new Regex(".").Replace(s, "*", 3, 1);
```

Comment: В данном случае используется паттерн `"."` (один любой символ).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Попробуй s = s.Insert(index, "***");</strike>

```
string strCount = "";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    strCount += "*";
s.Insert(index, strCount);
```

Comment: Во-первых получается "..***...".Во-вторых я хочу,это потом загнать в цикл.Для решения более глобальной задачи.Конечно можно последнюю точку удалить.Но мне такой вариант не подходит.Мне нужно что-то вроде s = s.Insert(index, "*",3);если бы так можно было естественно.

Comment: @FaradeyInimicos http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443446/179270